# SQL Removing Duplicate rows

Tags: sql, select, duplicates

I've been trying to remove duplicates using HAVING count(*) > 1, group by, distinct and sub queries but can't get any of these to work..

```
SELECT UserID,  BuildingNo    
FROM  Staff INNER JOIN TblBuildings ON Staff.StaffID = 
TblBuildingsStaffID
GROUP BY TblStaff.User_Code, BuildingNo
```

What I get is..

```
StaffID1 | BuildingNo1
StaffID1 | BuildingNo2
StaffID2 | BuildingNo2
StaffID3 | BuildingNo1
StaffID3 | BuildingNo2
```

I'm trying to get it so it just displays staff with one building number (if they have two regardless of which it shows) like:

```
StaffID1 | BuildingNo1
StaffID2 | BuildingNo2
StaffID3 | BuildingNo1
```

It can't be too hard.. I've tried CTE's left joining the building to the staff table, these come up NULL for some reason when I try this

Any help would be great!

Comment: HINT: `MIN(BuildingNo)` & remove `BuildingNo` from `GROUP BY` Clause

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154251/1822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't group by `BuildingNo`, then you can use `having` to filter out the groups you want.

```
SELECT s.UserID, min(b.BuildingNo) as buildingno
FROM Staff s
   JOIN TblBuildings ON s.StaffID = b.TblBuildingsStaffID
GROUP BY s.UserID
having count(distinct b.BuildingNo) = 1;
```

The `min()` aggregate is required because `buildingno` is not part of the group by clause. But as the `having()` clause only returns those with one building, it doesn't change anything.

If you want to display all staff members, and simply pick one (arbitrary) building, then simply leave out the `having` condition.

If you want to include staff members *without* a building you need a left join:

```
SELECT s.UserID, min(b.BuildingNo) as buildingno
FROM Staff s
   LEFT JOIN TblBuildings b ON s.StaffID = t.TblBuildingsStaffID
GROUP BY t.UserID;
```

Comment: If this would run (it wouldn't since there's no "TblStaff.User_Code"), wouldn't it drop staffid1 and staffid3 from the list?  Their count(distinct BuildingNo) being 2.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: thanks, corrected the code (copy & paste from the question). It seems I mis-read the "*so it just displays staff with one building number *"

Comment: Yep, he meant "staff with one of their buildings".

Answer (score 0):

Use row partition keyword in your query to avoid duplicacy

```
   WITH CTE AS( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY UserID )  AS 'Num',UserID,  BuildingNo    
    FROM  Staff INNER JOIN TblBuildings ON Staff.StaffID = 
    TblBuildingsStaffID
    GROUP BY TblStaff.User_Code, BuildingNo)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE Num =1
```

Comment: Overkill.  As is "PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY UserID".  What's the use of ordering by UserID within a partition containing exactly one UserID?

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
SELECT distinct UserID,  BuildingNo    
FROM  Staff INNER JOIN TblBuildings ON Staff.StaffID = 
TblBuildingsStaffID
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer